# Is it possible to remain in fullscreen mode with another window having focus?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I have a flash panorama that has hotspot links to pop-up windows that contain more information about the object.  Right now if you are in fullscreen mode and click a hotspot you are automatically kicked out of fullscreen mode and the pop-up then opens.  Is it possible to have the pop-up open and have focus while in the background the panorama is still in fullscreen mode?  If so any tips on how to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **NO**, somehow it makes sense otherwise why would it be fullscreen if you could overlap it with pop-ups? The fullscreen is made to focus only on one window. If you want to have more information coming up, why not doing them inside your SWF ?

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, generating the pop within the swf is very much so possible it just increases the complexity of the project immensely.

Answer (score 1):

No but what you can do is make the form the same size as your resolution and hide taskbar and frame.